# Sharepoint REST API - Create InformationRightsManagementSettings

Tags: sharepoint-addin, rest, irm

To create IRM settings using REST API, I am referring to document https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj247077.aspx

As per documentation, it suggest below REST endpoint to create new IRM:

```
POST http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/lists(listid)/InformationRightsManagementSettings
```

Howerver the post body is not given in documentation. I tried using below as post body however API is returning Bad request.

```
POST body : {'policyTitle':'IRM'}
```

Need to understand how to set IRM setting object properties.